# Accordion Jquery Multi-menu nav

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm doing an accordion menu bar, problem is when i click a link without a children menu the links that has children are still opened, Can somebody help me on how to fix or improve my jquery, what i want is like.. If i click the link without child, all accordion are set to close.

```
function initMenu() {
    $(".sub-menu").hide();
    $('#accordion1 li a').click(
    function () {
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
            return false;
        }
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#accordion1 ul:visible').not(checkElement.parentsUntil('#accordion1')).slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.current-menu-item').parentsUntil('#accordion1').slideDown('normal');
}
$(function () {
    initMenu();
});
$(function () {
    var selector = '.menu li';
    $(selector).on('click', function () {
        $(selector).removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
    $('.menu').delegate('li', 'click', function () {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

here the **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/carljohntorres/zrnga1w0/1/)**

Comment: something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/8hue16yc/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your click function at the top:
**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zrnga1w0/2/)**

```
if($(this).parent().children('ul').length<1)
{
     $('#accordion1 ul:visible').not(checkElement.parentsUntil('#accordion1')).slideUp('normal');  
}
```

**EDIT 1**

Add this below code for the problem you mentioned in your comment:

```
if($(this).parents('ul').length>1 && $(this).parent().children('ul').length==0)
{
     return;   
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zrnga1w0/3/)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! My requirement is... When I click the 4th level sub-menu (Revenue Collection Officer Module > Reprint > eReceipt Number > Official Receipt) the accordion should stay open in that particular sub-menu then if I click the Dashboard that's the "only time" the accordion will close.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! When I click the Dashboard (which is the 1st level) all accordion are closed. It's working! 

but when I click the 4th level sub-menus that doesn't have children.. the accordion should remain opened. How will I do that? 

Thank you very much.

Comment: That can be done easily but right now am away from system. I can answer you tomorrow morning after 9 am IST

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! When I click the Dashboard (which is the 1st level) all accordion are closed. It's working! but when I click the 4th level sub-menus that doesn't have children.. the accordion should remain opened. How will I do that? Thank you very much.

Comment: @CJohn.. Updated the answer.. Just check and let me know if any problem!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your work, now its working 100%

Comment: Anytime @CJohn.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/8hue16yc/) is my implementation of the same.

```
function initMenu() {
    $(".sub-menu").hide();
    $('#accordion1 li a').click(
    function () {
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        var allelems = $('#accordion1 li ul');
            allelems.not(checkElement).slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    });
}
$(function () {
    initMenu();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for response! Nice try but @Guruprasad Rao work is much better, only **1st level ** of menu will collapse all accordion like (dashboard) not from sub-menu, but then thank you again.